# how to disable/remove nfs4 acl, and back to original linux access control?

Tags: nfs, access-control-list, nfs4, posix, network-filesystem

I have add nfs4 acl for a directory in nfs client, but can not use "chown/chgrp" after add nfs4 acl, now I want to give up nfs4 acl, and back to original linux simple access control, how to ???

In standard linux acl, we can use `setfacl -bn xxx file` to remove all acl, and back to original access control, but I do not know how to do it by nfs4_setfacl...

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a random file to see the default NFS4 ACL: `touch /tmp/foo`
2. Store the default ACLs in a file: `nfs4_getfacl /tmp/foo > /tmp/fooacl.txt`
3. Restore recursively the ACL in repo BAR: `nfs4_setfacl -R -S /tmp/fooacl.txt /path/to/BAR`

You could also use a find command if the `-R` is too scary:

```
find /path/to/BAR -exec nfs4_setfacl -S /tmp/fooacl.txt {} \;
```

I would not recommand the solution from kofemann if you need to do something recursively. Or be sure to test it before applying it on your $HOME. I had a bad result on a test that locked me out of my own repository.

Answer (score 0):

My solution will be as:

```
nfs4_getfacl <file> | nfs4_setfacl -X - <file>
```